# If $M$ is a submanifold of $\mathbb R^3$ and the normal space $N$ on $M$ at $p$ is one-dimensional, can we choose an unique "outer" normal from $N$?

Tags: differential-geometry, manifolds, smooth-manifolds

Let $M$ be a two-dimensional submanifold of $\mathbb R^3$. Then, the normal space $N_p(M)$ on $M$ at $p\in M$ is one-dimensional. So, there are only two unit normal vectors $n_1$ and $n_2$ on $M$ at $p$.

Can we somehow choose an "outer" one $\nu(p)\in\left\{n_1,n_2\right\}$?

$\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;$[image]

I only know the definition of the *outer normal field* $\nu:\partial K\to\mathbb R^n$ for a compact space $K\subseteq\mathbb R^n$ with a smooth boundary $\partial K$. In this case, there is an open environment $U$ of $p\in\partial K$ and some $\psi\in C^1(U)$ such that

- $K\cap U=\left\{\psi\le 0\right\}$
- $\psi'\ne 0$

and it's easy to see, that $$\nu(p):=\frac{\nabla\psi(p)}{\left\|\nabla\psi(p)\right\|}\tag 1$$ is the unique $n\in N_p(\partial K)$ such that $\left\|n\right\|=1$ and $$p+tn\not\in K\;\;\;\text{for all }t\in (0,\varepsilon)$$ for some $\varepsilon>0$. Moreover, it's easy to see from $(1)$ that $\nu:\partial K\to\mathbb R^n$ is continuous.

> Can we find a similiar mapping $\nu:M\to\mathbb R^3$ which is at least Borel-measurable?

Comment: This really isn't my field of expertise but I feel like you're going to have trouble when $M$ is non-orientable?

Comment: It seems like you've given a pretty good answer already: if you can write your manifold $M$ as $\{\psi =0\}$ for some sufficiently regular function $\psi$, then $\pm \nabla\psi/\|\nabla\psi\|$ give the unit normal vectors (compactness of $M$ is not necessary). Another standard way of producing normal vectors is with parameterizations. That is, if $U\subseteq \mathbb{R}^2$ is open, and $f\colon U\to M\subset\mathbb{R}^3$ is a diffeomorphism onto an open subset of $M$, then the cross product of the partial derivatives $f_x(p)\times f_y(p)$ is normal to $M$ at $f(p)$ for all $p\in U$.

Comment: @froggie I thought this would be to restrictive. I've read that it's sufficient to assume that $M$ is a piecewise differentiable manifold with boundary, but I wasn't able to figure out whether or not $N_p(M)$ would have dimension $1$, for all $p\in M$, in this generality.

Comment: If $M$ is a $2$ dimensional manifold, then its tangent space at any point has dimension $2$. If $M$ is embedded in $\mathbb{R}^3$, that means the dimension of the tangent space plus the dimension of the normal space must be $3$, so the dimension of the normal space is $1$.

Comment: @froggie Sorry, you're right. The real problem I'm curious about is whether or not we can find a continuous mapping $\nu:M\to\mathbb R^3$ such that $\nu(p)\in N_p(M)$ is the unique unit normal which "points out of the surface" (as in the pictures).

Comment: @BenMillwood It's not possible to embed a (closed) nonorientable surface in $\mathbb{R}^3$.

Comment: I think the idea of "outside" can really be subtle. For instance, if your surface is not orientable (like a Mobius band), then the word "outside" really has no meaning. But even for something like the triangle in your pictures: why is the normal vector you've drawn the "outside" one? Or imagine two cubes, one whose top face is a square in the $xy$-plane and another of the same size sitting on top of the first, so that its bottom face is the same square in the $xy$-plane. For these cubes, the outer normal vectors will be pointing different directions on this square.

Answer (score 0):

What you are seeking for is called the [Gauss map](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gauss_map). Although the wikipedia article is pretty informative, it fails to mention that it is the *outer normal* which the Gauss map produces, so it does answer your question.

Answer (score 0):

You said in a comment (which has been deleted) that you're most interested in the case of flat polygons in space. Any flat polygon is a piece of a plane, and all planes in space have an equation of the form $Ax + By + Cz = D$, where $A$, $B$, $C$, and $D$ are constants. Moreover, if you know this equation, it is super easy to cook up a (not necessarily unit) normal vector, namely the vector $\langle A, B, C\rangle$.

Or, if you don't have the equation for the plane, but instead have three non-colinear points $P$, $Q$, and $R$ on the plane, you can determine a (not necessarily unit) normal vector to the plane with a cross product: $\vec{PQ}\times \vec{PR}$

Comment: I want to leave $M$ as general as possible and want to make sure that any assumption I make on $M$ doesn't exclude the case in which $M$ is a triangle. Since $M$ is a two-dimensional submanifold, the normal spaces have dimension $1$ (as you've pointed out in a comment). So, the only problem I'm concerned about is whether or not the mapping $x\mapsto n_x$ which maps $x\in M$ to it's unique unit normal which "points out of $M$ (as in the pictures) exists and is continuous.

Comment: Assuming it is orientable (so for instance, not a Mobius band), a surface in $\mathbb{R}^3$ always has a continuously varying (even smoothly varying) unit normal vector field. As for the notion of "outside" this only makes sense if the surface you're considering is closed. For instance, the sphere is closed, so it makes sense to talk about an outward unit normal, but the triangle in your pictures is not closed, so it is a choice to call the arrow you've drawn "outward" while the opposite is "inward".